# Menu structure and URL paths

Tags: routes, path-aliases, navigation

I am using a Superfish 2 level navigation menu, and have 3 sub-items under an item. 
The url path for the second level item is NOT item/subitem but instead just subitem, if that makes sense.

I've got Generate automatic URL alias checked.

Is it acceptable for the subitems to not have their parent items in the url path? If not, what is the easiest way to automatically have the item appended to the subitems url path?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is acceptable for child menu items to not contain any of the parent item's path.

Comment: Can you please explain ?

Comment: I can create a menu item in the main menu that has the path "news". I can then create a child menu item of that menu that is "faq". The paths are completely unrelated but they are still parent - child items and the child will be in the drop down of the parent.

Comment: Its cool +1, we expect detailed answer here, than a one liner. whatever simple it is.